# Is SOA mostly a bunch of web services?

Tags: soa

Learning about SOA.  Is it mostly decoupling by way of web services, one service provides web services to another, thereby staying decoupled and encapsulated?  Thanks.

edit:  that and maybe a good front end to them like some MVC design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOA is commonly implemented using web services but can be implemented using any method of decoupling the service implementation from the interface. These are then often presented to the business in a directory when apps can request details for any service provision that offers the desired service criteria.

MVC is a pattern for applications that could access SOA but I would use the best pattern for your application rather than trying to shoehorn into a single pattern. Just remember that SOA calls are likely to be operated asynchronously.

Comment: What does that last part mean:  "likely to be operated asynchronously"?  Thanks.

Comment: It's not normal to use SOA services synchronously, i.e. you connect and perform several transactions and receive results, then disconnect. You're more likely to connect, fire off your request and then get on with other activities while your request is processed and the result returned at which point your app processes the results. In the Enterprise space you often find the SOA centred around a service bus that mediates these comms, like MQ or similar.

Comment: so you have some kind of callback like in ajax so you know when the service is done?

Comment: Yes. Absolutely, a callback is a common construct for asynchronous method/function calls.

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538710/reports-in-soa-business-intelligence-service-oriented-architecture ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer I provided to another question a while ago which may help with SOA principles: [Rebuild N-tier app into Service-Oriented Architecture (SOA)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349352/rebuild-n-tier-app-into-service-oriented-architecture-soa/2366496#2366496)

Also the following is an intro to SOA: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-soa-design1/

In short there's a lot more to it than just web-services, its how you make available coarse grained 'business services' for reuse by multiple systems, and how you then make calls across multiple business services to meet wider business processes.

Developing some web-services != SOA

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good selection of links that challenge the idea that SOA is only about web services, it explores the idea that every class in the application is a service and we can use many different transports (web, tcp, queues) within our SOA. SOA is the methodology you use to build a service orientated application.

Here are some practical examples of how to build a SOA.

I would suggest you read articles by Thomas Erl and Roger Sessions, this will give you a firm handle on what SOA is all about.

[SOA Design Pattern](http://hubpages.com/_1k9ore6as3b3m/hub/ASP-NET-MVC-Patterns)

[Achieving integrity in a SOA](http://hubpages.com/_1k9ore6as3b3m/hub/Achieving-Non-Functional-Requirements-for-a-Service-Oriented-Software-Platform-Integrity)

[Why your SOA should be like a VW Beetle](http://hubpages.com/_1k9ore6as3b3m/hub/Why-your-Service-Orientated-Architecture-SOA-needs-to-be-like-a-VW-Beetle)

[SOA explained for your boss](http://hubpages.com/_1k9ore6as3b3m/hub/soa-with-wcf)

[Building a SOA](http://hubpages.com/_1k9ore6as3b3m/hub/Building-Service-Orientated-Architecture)

[WCF Service Performance](http://hubpages.com/_1k9ore6as3b3m/hub/WCF-Service-Performance)

Choosing a presentation pattern for a new or enterprise web development  is a daunting task, in my opinion there are only three; View Model, Model-View-Presenter (MVP) or ASP.NET MVC (a Model2 derivative).

You can read the full article here [ASP.NET MVC Patterns](http://hubpages.com/_1k9ore6as3b3m/hub/ASP-NET-MVC-Patterns)

Answer (score 0):

Despite the (incorrect) selected answer I have to state that SOA has nothing to do with web services.
The "service" term is so overloaded in English, so people are getting confused sometimes.

SOA is an architectural style, a set of guidances and principles that help us model our systems as "systems which consist of other systems".
The service term in SOA can be defined as a "technical authority for a specific business capability".
SOA helps to deal with coupling between capabilities, including temporal and spatial coupling.

As you can see, designing your system as an open set of loosely coupled and self-responsible systems (services) has nothing to do with using web services, WCF or other "cool things". You may use them or you may not use them. Or use them in one context, but not in another.

Most definitely you will NOT use web services as a communication protocol between your services in SOA because they immediately introduce temporal and spatial coupling.

Comment: I think I'd need more information before I can say the selected answer is wrong.